# proof of existence $x$ such that $x^2=-1$ in a ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]/(p)$ when $p$ is prime in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$.

Tags: ring-theory

I got stuck in a question in my graduate level course - ring and fields.

In the first part of the question we show that if there exists $a,b$ in $\mathbb Z$ such that $a^2+3\cdot b^2=c$ then $c=0,1,3,4,7$ mod $9$.

Then in the second part we show that if $p$ is odd prime (in $\mathbb Z$) such that $p=2,5,6,8 \text { mod } 9$ then $p$ is prime in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}].$

I succeeded solving these first two parts.

The last part I got stuck with and could not solve:

$p$ is odd prime (in $\mathbb Z$) such that $ p=2,5,6,8 \text { mod } 9$,
then in the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]/(p)$ exists $x$ such that $x^2=-1$.

Comment: Hint: $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]/(p)\cong \Bbb F_{p^2}$, how many elements does $\Bbb F_{p^2}^\times$ have and what does this have to do with $-1$ being a square?

Comment: This might be irrelevant to the question, but there are no primes $p \equiv 6$ mod $9$ in $\mathbb Z$. -- Regarding the question, have you computed a few examples?

Comment: @torsten do negative primes count? Then $-3\equiv6\bmod9$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: Ha, good point. Well then there's one, and that one is done by hand ...

Comment: ... and actually, unless I'm totally blind, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]/(3)$ does *not* contain a square root of $-1$ (it is $\simeq \mathbb F_3[x]/(x^2)$). And I think when classifying prime numbers depending on some congruences modulo a modulus, mostly we mean positive prime numbers. Otherwise e.g. all discussions based on the dichotomy $p \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 4$ versus $p \equiv 3 \text{ mod } 4$ would be a bit ridiculous ...